# HDD unpluged for a long period of time goes bad?

Tags: backup, hard-drive, storage, drive

I have two HDD's unplugged for two years. It's from my old pc. I have some important files in there but I'm wondering about this problem.

Will the HDD's turn on and I'll be able to access all my files or there a possibility of these HDD's goes bad because I let them off for a long time?

People, the old question is from 2009... Now, the HDD's are different. I need a new question, a new debate from the experience from users since 2009.

Comment: Maybe plug them in and find out?

Answer (score 0):

HDDs are magnetical recording system, so they can lose magnetization (ie: your data) when powered off for extended time period. An ever bigger problem can arise from the lubrificant and moving parts (ie: actuator and motor) being "inactive" for so much time.

That said, two years are not *so much* time; I am quite confident that your HDD will read just fine. But hey - try them and report back!